# open with O_RDWR -- how to overwrite?

Tags: c, file-io

I want to read a file and change its content and write it back to the file.

I use `open` to read a file as follows:

```
bfd = open(m_file_name.c_str(), O_RDWR)
```

But when I write, it is kinda append it to the old one. How can I overwrite it?

Comment: look at the manpage for fseek

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: `fseek` does not work with file descriptors, only with `FILE *`.  You are thinking of `lseek`.

Comment: @Dietrich thanks, I probably shouldn't have posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lseek(2)`

```
bfd = open(m_file_name.c_str(), O_RDWR);
// read your file
lseek(bfd, 0, SEEK_SET);
// do whatever manipulation & write file
```

If your file is now less in size than the original, you will need to truncate the size to the new size, or you'll leave the bytes from the old end of the file at the end. If it's larger, the file should grow automatically as you write.

Comment: No the size are the same.. let me check see it works or not... :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to seek with `lseek` if you want to write at a specific position.

You are not trying to overwrite the entire file, right?  Just a small part of it?  If you are trying to overwrite the entire file then this is a bad way to do it.

Comment: I want to overwrite it... the size of the file remains intact

Comment: If you overwrite the entire file, it is better to open a new file with `O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL` and then move it over the old file.  This way, if your program crashes, you won't lose the original file.